# Can Ping & HTTP but not SMTP from a host

Tags: networking, smtp

I have an Ubuntu 14 Server host. I can ping and HTTP to an external server, but cannot SMTP to it.

Doing `host mail.domain.com` returns the correct external address, so DNS is working. Doing `ping mail.domain.com` shows me that we successfully reach the server. Doing `telnet mail.domain.com 80` shows me I get the expected 400 error. Doing a `curl` also shows the expected data.

But, doing a `telnet mail.domain.com 25` gives me a `telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused`. Doing a `traceroute mail.domain.com` shows that I presumably go a few hops outside of the Ubuntu server, across some Comcast nodes, but then fail out?

```
 1  <hidden>
 2  <hidden>
 3  <hidden>
 4  pos-3-15-0-0-cr01.56marietta.ga.ibone.comcast.net (68.86.91.221)  17.061 ms pos-0-6-0-0-cr01.miami.fl.ibone.comcast.net (68.86.95.57)  11.345 ms pos-3-15-0-0-cr01.56marietta.ga.ibone.comcast.net (68.86.91.221)  17.052 ms
 5  he-0-11-0-1-pe04.56marietta.ga.ibone.comcast.net (68.86.89.94)  15.382 ms  15.381 ms be-15-pe02.nota.fl.ibone.comcast.net (68.86.83.146)  8.659 ms
 6  65.124.97.177 (65.124.97.177)  50.463 ms  49.446 ms  49.418 ms
 7  * * *
 8  63.148.218.166 (63.148.218.166)  85.529 ms  75.366 ms  75.155 ms
 9  216.197.122.66 (216.197.122.66)  83.499 ms  77.650 ms  77.689 ms
10  * * *
11  * * *
```

From another (Windows 7) box on the local network, that telnet command works fine, with the expected 220 SMTP message.

```
1     <hidden>
2     <hidden>
3     <hidden>
4    10 ms    11 ms    19 ms  pos-3-15-0-0-cr01.56marietta.ga.ibone.comcast.net [68.86.91.221]
5     8 ms     8 ms     8 ms  be-12-pe02.nota.fl.ibone.comcast.net [68.86.82.121]
6    48 ms    48 ms    53 ms  nap-edge-04.inet.qwest.net [65.122.166.77]
7     *        *        *     Request timed out.
8    75 ms    73 ms    75 ms  63.148.218.166
9    75 ms    75 ms    75 ms  216.197.122.66
10    75 ms    70 ms    70 ms  216.119.120.174
11    76 ms    76 ms    76 ms  mail.domain.com
```

Steps 1-3 show the same data. Any suggestions? Why would packets from one box get routed differently than another coming from the same network?

Comment: Yes, it is corporate. But, traceroute shows I am exiting my local network and going into Comcast's from both systems?

Comment: Touche. :) The Windows machine reached the server on port 25.

Comment: I've moved the gist of my comments to an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that this is a corporate situation, the most plausible culprit is the company firewall. Like in most corporate set-ups, the firewall rejects all outbound TCP port 25 connections, except those originating from designated machines. The Windows server probably is one of these, and the Ubuntu server isn't.

To find out whether this is the case, perform any of these diagnostics, in decreasing order of sensibility:

1. Ask the network administrators. They know.
2. Run `tcptraceroute mail.domain.com 25` from the Ubuntu server to find out which hop is rejecting the establishment of an SMTP connection.
3. Assign the IP address of the Windows server to the Ubuntu server. Pull out the network cable from the Windows server. Try `telnet mail.domain.com 25` from the Ubuntu server. Better not tell the network administrators.

From these diagnostics you will find out whether the TCP connection is blocked within the company, at the destination, or somewhere in between. I'd say the odds for these are 1G:10:1. In either case, you will need to talk to the network administrators to solve the issue, so you might as well take step 1 right away.

Note that it makes no sense to do a `traceroute` when you can already `ping` a destination. The successful ping proves that the destination is live and reachable. Therefore all hops in between are reachable. No need to demonstrate that.

Comment: I concur to this answer. I work for a local cell phone company and the server team cant even install a new server without getting network team to open ports first. And i have learned from experience using a home internet connection, most ISPs block ports 25,21,22 and so on. My ISP told me they do not block ports, and after a week of trouble shooting i called them for help and another tech told me they do block them for security reasons.

Comment: Dang it. I know that, but ignored it. Turns out someone had added a temporary rule on the DMZ firewall that governed that system because of a spam issue... and forgot to remove it.